# SQL Cursor advice needed - Checking a list of unique dates within a set of date ranges

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I'm self-taught in T-SQL, so forgive me if I'm asking a question with a simple answer, but I've hit the end of my knowledge, and my internet searching isn't teaching me what I'm looking for...

I have two tables I'm working with:

```
tbl_A (exit)
----------------------------
id_num | exit_dte
----------------------------
100001 | 2001-01-15
100002 | 2001-01-31
100003 | 2001-06-03

tbl_B (period)
---------------------------------------------
period_id | period_start_dte | period_end_dte
---------------------------------------------
        1 |       2001-01-01 |     2001-01-31
        2 |       2001-07-01 |     2001-07-31
```

The system interface allows users of the data to put any date they want into tbl_A.exit_dte, though their (unwritten) business policies state that they shouldn't put a date into that column that doesn't fall between the period_start_dte and period_end_dte of a record in the tbl_B. I need to find any exit_dte that doesn't fall between the start and end of a period_id.

My first step is to prepare a distinct list of the existing tbl_A.exit_dte values. This I know how to do:

```
Select distinct tbl_A.exit_dte from tbl_A
```

What I don't know how to do, but what I think I want to do, is to use a cursor to loop across the values of this list, and for each value, determine whether it falls between the start and end dates of a period in tbl_B. If it is within a period date range, I'll show "In Range"; otherwise, I'd show "Error" (The descriptors are irrelevant, I understand).

```
2001-01-15 | In Range  (matches tbl_B.period_id = 1)
2001-01-31 | In Range  (matches tbl_B.period_id = 1) 
2001-06-03 | Error
```

Here's what I've tried in order to get my desired results:

```
    Declare @ques_dte datetime
    Declare @Getid cursor

    Set @Getid = CURSOR FOR
    Select distinct exit_dte
    from tbl_A

    Open @Getid
    Fetch NEXT
    from @Getid into @ques_dte

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    Begin

        select
        @ques_dte as checked_date
        , case 
            when tbl_B.period_id is not null then 'In Range'
            else 'Error' end as Date_Period_Check
        from tbl_B
        where @ques_dte between tbl_B.period_start_dte and tbl_B.period_end_dte

        Fetch NEXT
        From @Getid INTO @ques_dte
    END

    Close @Getid
    Deallocate @Getid
```

So, the query doesn't blow up when I run it (always a good sign), but there are several issues. First, the results in SSMS make it appear like it's running a distinct query for each of the @ques_dte values (It probably is), rather than one long set of results. I'm sure this is due to my improper understanding of the CURSOR operation of BEGIN, FETCH, END.

Second, while the query displays @ques_dte that **match** a tbl_B.period_id, and shows the "In Range" value, those @ques_dte which **don't match**, don't display either @ques_dte or the "Error" value - it's just a null recordset. I'm baffled about this.

Third, (and this may be because I'm impatient and not understanding the difference between set-based SQL operations, and whatever this is...) the query seems to take long time to run. In my production environment, there are 164 records in tbl_B, and 1011 records in distinct query coming out of tbl_A. Those seem like small numbers, yet the query takes 29 seconds to complete.

I'd welcome expert feedback and advice. I don't really care about the execution time that much - I can live with a delay - but if someone would be willing to educate me on my first two issues, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: what is your expected result in this case?

Comment: Thanks to both Zohar Peled and Rigerta, as their answers both solve my question. I appreciate it very much - I've used the Left join in other settings, and used the CASE statement for null values, but hadn't considered to use it in this fashion. So simple, once it's suggested. I don't seem to be able to mark both responses as answers, so I've left both unchecked, but they both are viable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like a simple left join will do the trick:

```
SELECT id_num, exit_dte, period_id
FROM [exit] 
LEFT JOIN period 
ON exit_dte > period_statt_dte
AND exit_dte < period_end_dte
```

You will get the period_id of the range for dates that fall within a range, and null for dates that doesn't.

If you want to show 'In Range' and 'Error', you can use case:

```
SELECT  exit_dte, 
        CASE WHEN period_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
            'In Range' 
        ELSE
            'Error' 
        END
FROM [exit] 
LEFT JOIN period 
ON exit_dte > period_statt_dte
AND exit_dte < period_end_dte
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be what you need and it would be done based on a set of data instead of going one by one at each row (as the cursor would do) of the second table:

```
select id_num, exit_dte 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.exit_dte between period_start_dte and period_end_dte
where t2.period_id is null
```